# Launch/Resume Flow when a button is clicked

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to create a button wherein I can either launch a flow if there's no existing FlowInterview, else launch the flow.

This article from Salesforce is perfect, but when I tried to copy the code and change the flow API from the Controller I'm having an error.

Article:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_resume.htm

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="InterviewsController">
<lightning:button label="Button1" title="Neutral action" name="init" value="{!this}" onclick="{!c.init}"/>
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        
        var action = component.get("c.getPausedId");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var interviewId = response.getReturnValue();
            
            var flow = component.find("flowData");
            
             if ( interviewId !== null )  { 
                flow.resumeFlow(interviewId);
            }
            
            else {
                flow.startFlow("Test_Flow");
            }
        });
        console.log('************* '+interviewId);
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

Apex

```
public class InterviewsController {
   @AuraEnabled
   public static String getPausedId() {
      // Get the ID of the running user
      String currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
      // Find all of that user's paused interviews for the Survey customers flow
      List<FlowInterview> interviews =
         [ SELECT Id FROM FlowInterview
           WHERE CreatedById = :currentUser AND InterviewLabel LIKE '%Test Flow%'];
      
      if (interviews == null || interviews.isEmpty()) {
         return null; // early out
      }
      // Return the ID for the first interview in the list
      return interviews.get(0).Id;
   }
}
```

I'm currently experiencing the error below

> [interviewId is not defined]

Comment: Hi , The Apex controller defined in the Aura component is different to the Apex controller which you have written the code. Can you please check and correct it

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala All correct, in my code I'm using the correct Controller.